Having a hard time dealing with cron-job.org API
I want to create a cron job on cron-job.org through their API using python.
As a result, I get 404.
I don't know exactly what is not found
from datetime import datetime
import requests, json

# Cron-job.org API URL
api_url = "https://cron-job.org/api/1.0/user/cronjobs"
# api_url = "https://api.cron-job.org"

# Your cron-job.org API key
api_key = "*******************************************"

# Cron job details
command_url = f"https://httpbin.org/json"

# Extract hour and minute
try:
    hour = 10
    minute = 30

    # Prepare cron job schedule (cron-job.org takes time in hour and minute, not the standard cron format)
    schedule = {
    "minute": minute,
    "hour": hour,
    "mdays": ["*"],  # Every day of the month
    "months": ["*"], # Every month
    "wdays": ["*"],  # Every day of the week
    "enabled": True,
    "url": command_url
    }

    # Create headers with API key for authentication
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    # Make the API request to create the cron job
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(
    schedule))

    # Check if the cron job was created successfully
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Cron job created successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to create cron job: {response}")
        print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Errrrrrror: {e}')

I tried to change the command_url just in case and also search for possible api links but same resault.

Do you have any documentation for that endpoint you are using there? I can only find https://docs.cron-job.org/rest-api.html#creating-a-cron-job, and that says you should make a PUT request to /jobs ...?

@C3roe Thanks for highlighting "put" method, the error went from 404 to 400! That's a good sign

I found out that we should use put method instead of post
Also, the API URL must be: api_url = "https://api.cron-job.org/jobs"
Finally, the bare minimum of params should be:
"job": {
    "url": command_url,
    "enabled": True,
    "saveResponses": True,
    "schedule": {
        "timezone": "GMT",
        "expiresAt": 0,
        "hours": [hour],    
        "minutes": [minute],
        "mdays": [-1],      
        "months": [-1],     
        "wdays": [-1]       
    }
}

